# Unattended updates: why are some security updates not installed, is it based on the kernel version?

Tags: upgrade

Unattended upgrades are being installed on my servers

As an example of an unattended upgrade:

```
openssh-server                      1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.11
```

On system1 I see that `openssh-server` `1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.1`0 is still there, while `openssh-sftp-server` has been updated to `1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.11`

On system2 I see that both packages have been upgraded to `1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.11`

There is a dist difference between both servers:

- system1:

  ```
  Linux 3.13.0-141-generic #190-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 12:52:38 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- system2:

  ```
  Linux 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```

So on the newer one (system2) the package upgrade has not been done. Why is this?

Comment: Sorry, it shoud have been openssh-sftp-server :s
My main concern is, why is openssh-server not updated to the latest security patch?

Comment: Comments are not intended for conversation. To make a correction or clarification, please edit your question. Check your unattended-upgrades logs to see when U-U last ran on each system, and what it's logic concluded in each case. `openssh-server` was updated on 06 Nov 2018, allow an extra day-or-two for timezones and mirrors to sync.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the 'MinimalSteps' setting of unattended updates configuration seems to solve the problem (for the kernel we use, although not all server have this problem). https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/sicherheits-aktualisierungen-werden-nicht-mehr/